# What does 脫上台 in the following context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This line comes from the song 走建國路回家但後座少ㄌ泥. Lyrics can be found [here](https://www.kkbox.com/tw/tc/song/4qgJUfy8WUFospwa1V) if more context is needed.

> 知道妳喜歡自由, 不會去管你太多就算妳說**上台要脫**

I know you like freedom, so I won't bother you too much, even if... What? "Need to get of the stage" is the best I've come up with but that can't be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

上台要脫 means `take off my clothes on stage`.

Comment: Oh! I knew 脫 means to undress but had never made the connection here. So he's basically saying "I know you like freedom, so even if you say you're going to get up on stage and strip, I won't stop you"?

Comment: word by word,  ( on stage )  ( take it off )

Comment: `I won't bother you` is better expression